# If I factory reset my phone will that change the phone number?

Tags: factory-reset, hardware

Last time it did. will it? because I forgot.

Comment: I don't think that's possible considering such information is stored on the chip of the Subscriber Identity Module, and resetting involves just re-writing the relevant partitions on device storage and is not related to SIM, you could always remove the SIM card first prior to factory reset , but AFAIK it won't change your phone number

Comment: Is there any other way? cuz I want to receive sms from Facebook for free without using my already used phone number.

Comment: I have never used Facebook, but I think you don't get charged for SMS verifications/ OTP messages, but if you have registered for Facebook with that number wont it be easier to click the "forgot password" link to recover your account? (Note: As I said before I don't know how exactly it works with Facebook, I have never used it before)

Answer (score 1):

Factory reset has nothing to do with your phone number of your sim and as stated by comment above you can always remove your sim before resetting and reinsert after that and it has nothing to do with facebook message as when you reinsert you will receive messages as you are receiving currently 
 
**TL;DR resetting won't affect sim number or facebook messages**

Answer (score 0):

no it do not change your sim card number but all the contacts on your phone will be lost